# Python : selenium click on submit no redirect

Tags: python, django, selenium, testing, submit

I'm testing my django administration with Selenium.
It's working fine until i want to submit my form.

```
self.webdriver.find_element_by_name('_save').click()
```

Here is the html :

```
<input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="default" name="_save">
```

So it should redirect me to another page, or atleast refresh this page printing errors. But it doesn't.

Do you know why submitting doesn't redirect me ?

BTW : When i do it manually using my browser, it redirects me.

Comment: Check `print(len(self.webdriver.find_elements_by_name('_save')))`. Does it returns you `1`? If it returns `1` try `self.webdriver.find_element_by_name('_save').submit()`

Comment: Tried right now, it does !

Comment: Is there any error , if so please update the question with error trace.

Comment: Nop, no error. The problem is simple : clicking on the submit button does not submit the form.

Comment: DId you find a solution since? I've got an error which looks like yours

Answer (score 0):

You can wait till the element become clickable and then try to click on it.This may solve your issue.

```
submit = WebDriverWait(self.webdriver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "_save")))  
submit.click()
```

Comment: Well the driver click on that submit button, but there is still no redirection. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes. The weirdest thing is that it's not even my code, it's django admin.

Comment: @AntoineLB : after click try to reload the page and check by clicking on submit button again , whether you are able to redirect or not.

Comment: using selenium , manually I believe everything is working fine.

Comment: Still the same :/ No redirection while form is complete, and no error message.

Comment: It's quite strange :(